# Debian Server no HTTP response data

Tags: jquery, http

i have a little problem with my Server. I moved a an Application from one Server to another. The Webpage is available and works fine. But my ajax calls do not work fine. jQuery is active and works, the $.post also works and waits for a json response. And there is the problem, no response data is comming back from the script. i tried several things and can´t figure out where the problem is. Do i have to enable anything special on my Server to allow HTTP responses ??

I also tried to pass data wothout json encoding, but there is nothing ! I think its a Server setting problem, but i´m not that pro on Servertechnics :)

Anyone any suggestions ??

Thanks
Marc

Comment: do you have the hostname of your old server hard-coded into the ajax request url? are there any js errors appearing in the browser console?

Comment: nope. its an old project where i used codeigniter but i´ve checked that, i used the "site_url()" - function! i have an jquery error jquery-1.10.2.min.map -> 404 Not found! But jquery works i tried some console.logs and alerts. the local jQuer file has no errors.

Comment: what happens if you put the url that jquery is using in your browser address bar?

Comment: thats what i do atm :) and there is no output :( so there must be the problem anywhere

Comment: Ok i got it. Its the short syntax for if statements :) can i enable that in my php.ini ?

Comment: ok. so even if i try this : 
`if (!empty($this->input->post('barriere'))) {
  $attributes[] = '<strong>Barrierefrei:</strong> ' . $this->input->post('barriere');
  }`
it doenst work.... what im doing wrong !?!?

Answer (score 0):

Check address/domain name you use for your ajax calls. If you have your application running on domain test.com, ajax calls cannot access any other domain due to security restrictions.